# Output of for loop code snippet in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
i, j, k, u = 0, 5, 1, 3
for l in range(i, j, k):
    if l == u:
        print(l)
        u = 8
        i = 12
        j = 7
        k = -1
    else:
        print(l)
```

OUTPUT is :

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Why do we get this output?

Comment: What output were you expecting?

Comment: @Carcigenicate is right. We cannot help explain anything to you until we understand what _you_ were expecting.

Answer (score 1):

When Python first encounters the `for` loop, it builds the `range` object you requested: `range(0, 5, 1)`.  Once constructed, it controls the loop, and will *not* be reevaluated.  Changing the variable values during loop execution will not change the loop operation.

This means that, as far as the loop (or a sufficient optimizer) is concerned, your code looks like this:

```
i,j,k,u=0,5,1,3
for l in range(i,j,k) :
    print(l)

 u=8
 i=12
 j=7
 k=-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what output you expect. But since you change the values of the parameters used for generating the range I assume that you expect the output to be longer. At that point the list is already generated however and will not be affected.

In order to achieve the possibility of increasing the loop range during the looping I suggest you avoid the range function and consider using while instead of for.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Edit: Prune was both faster and better than me.

Comment: @Prune  and NacMacFeegle Thanks for your help, u solved the problem i had and  :)